RSpatial Terra: Rasterizing vector doesn't work
I’m working with a dataset containing around 400,000 1km x 1km grid cells in Japan, which I downloaded using the jpgrid package. The grid cells are stored as sf objects (polygons), but due to performance concerns, I would like to convert this dataset into raster layers. However, I’m encountering issues with the rasterization process using the terra package.
Here’s a reproducible example with a subset of the data:
library(tidyverse)
library(jpgrid)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(terra)

# Subset and preprocess the polygon data
cities_polygon <- head(grid_city_2020, n = 30) %>%
  grid_as_sf(crs = 6670) %>%
  mutate(key_code = as.character(grid),
         key_code = as.numeric(key_code)) %>%
  right_join(naro_2020, by = "key_code")

# Visualize the polygons (works as expected)
qtm(cities_polygon)

# Convert to a SpatVector and create a raster template
cities_vector <- vect(cities_polygon)
template_raster <- rast(ext = ext(cities_vector), 
                        resolution = 1000, 
                        crs = crs(cities_vector))

# Attempt to rasterize using a numeric field (error occurs here)
cities_raster <- rasterize(cities_vector, template_raster, field = "avg_hot_days_35")

# Plot the raster
plot(cities_raster)


The error I get after the cities_raster line is:
Warning: Failed to compute min/max, no valid pixels found in sampling. (GDAL error 1)

Thank you so much for any help!
What I’ve Tried:

Confirmed that the CRS of the SpatVector and raster template match.
Checked that the field column (avg_hot_days_35) contains numeric values with no missing values.
Made sure the geometries in cities_polygon are valid using st_is_valid() and makeValid().


Welcome to SO. Can you edit your question to make your code a self-contained, minimal, reproducible example? Your example is perhaps reproducible for you, but not for others (and that is what matters here) as it is not self-contained (it is not clear where the data come from). It is also not minimal (for example, there should be no need for packages tidyverse and tmap). Can you share cities_vector (ideally by recreating with R code, but if you must as a Rds file)?

It would be more efficient to rasterize the polygons as points. Can you do:
cities_vector <- vect(cities_polygon)
template_raster <- rast(cities_vector, resolution = 1000)
points_vector <- centroids(cities_vector)
cities_raster <- rasterize(points_vector, template_raster, field = "avg_hot_days_35")

